# How to reinstall Mac OS Snow Leopard from Grub

Tags: macos, install, snow-leopard

I tried install Ubuntu on the internal hard drive of my iMac and now want my iMac running Snow Leopard again

I can acquire a Snow Leopard ISO and burn it on to a CD through using my laptop. I don't know if that helps but I have that option. Grub does come up when I boot the Mac initially. But then I don't know where to go from there. Would it be wise of me to install the Windows 10 first that I have or should I just install the Mac image that I have?

Comment: Which Mac model do you have? Do you want to install macOS alongside Ubuntu or instead of?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  It’s hard to follow when you jump from burning an ISO to Grub coming up and then thinking about installing Windows 10.  We can’t  tell you how to move forward until you define what you want done.

Answer (score 1):

Either the Mac came with installation media which you can boot on (may need to press C or D while booting), or it has a rescue partition built in you can boot from using Command-R while booting (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Then proceed to use Disk Utility to completely wipe the drive, and then install MacOS/OS X.

Full details on https://support.apple.com/da-dk/HT204904

Comment: Snow Leopard (version 10.6) didn't have a Recovery partition; that was added in Lion (10.7). Snow Leopard was only available on DVD.

Comment: @gordon yes. Those machines came with bootable media hence that is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

By stating "again", I assume you had Snow Leopard installed at some previous time. Apple currently [posts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255): You can hold down the Option (⌥) or Alt at start up to boot to the Startup Manager, which allows you to choose other available startup disks or volumes. In this case you should select the optical drive containing the Snow Leopard DVD. [Another option](https://osxdaily.com/2010/04/12/boot-your-mac-from-a-cd-dvd/) would be to hold down the C key at startup.

In your question, you did not state the exact model of your iMac or the version of Snow Leopard, therefore there is no guarantee the version of Snow Leopard is compatible with your iMac. For example, if the iMac is a 27-inch, Mid 2010 model (which came pre-installed with Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.3) and the version of [Snow Leopard is OS X 10.6.0](https://ia800805.us.archive.org/15/items/SnowLeopardInstall/snow%20leopard%20install.JPG), then I would assume this version would not be usable.

If you do get Snow Leopard installed, then you should install the [Mac OS X 10.6.8 Update Combo v1.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1399?locale=en_US). You may have problems downloading using the iMac with Snow Leopard installed. You probably will want to download to a USB flash drive using Ubuntu on the iMac or your laptop.